# JavaME Date String to Long

Tags: datetime, blackberry, java-me

Im using SQLite and trying to get my date into a blackberry datetime field.

in the DB its stored as string in format:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

e.g. : 2012-02-01 15:45

But the field wants it as a Long.

`date - The initial date value for this field. This is the number of milliseconds since midnight on January 1, 1970. To create an empty date field, set this parameter to Long.MIN_VALUE. This method will then remove the date value from this field, setting it to null.`

And then convert it back again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check following code:

```
// conversion - string to long
long dateLong = HttpDateParser.parse("2012-04-17 16:09");

// conversion - long to string
Date dateObject = new Date(dateLong);        
String dateStr = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")).format(dateObject);
```

Comment: Works great. Any idea how to get it back from long to date again please? I dont actually need the time on return.

Comment: Check the code now. Confused about `Any idea how to get it back from long to date again please` - in which format you need your data back?. You can have the `Date` or `String`.

Comment: excellent answers. Yep, I mean date in string format aka, back to a string. Thanks a lot :)